# a package wants me to use a system mail name

Tags: software-installation, email, email-client

the full question is:
    The 'mail name' is the domain name used to 'qualify' mail addresses
    without a domain name.

```
This name will also be used by other programs. It should be the single,
fully qualified domain name (FQDN).  

Thus, if a mail address on the local host is foo@example.org, the
correct value for this option would be example.org
```

then it tells me to enter it. 
this error came up while i was installing some required packages for Hamachi
that it wouldn't install. thank you for any help.

Comment: If you have a domain you would type that in, otherwise, it is just the hostname of your computer.

Comment: How would I know what the host name of my computer is?

Comment: When you open a terminal, you will see a username@something.  That something is your hostname.   Or, you can just type in `hostname` at the prompt and it will show you.

Comment: Could you type up your comments as an answer so i can mark it as the answer?

Comment: Sure.  I'm not at my computer at the moment, but as soon as I get back I'll write it up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The application is asking for your domain name for emailing.  If you have a domain that you are on, you would just type that in like:

```
example.com
```

But if you don't have a domain that you are part of, the hostname of your computer would be the domain name.  To get your hostname, it is either the name right after the `@` in the terminal prompt, or you type in `hostname` from the prompt to get your hostname:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$

terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ hostname
terrance-ubuntu
```

Hope this helps!